# Making this CSS drawing responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I really like drawing with CSS, and I've just finished drawing this  Diglett using nothing more than CSS.

However, as good as it looks on my desktop, it isn't responsive and I don't know how to make it. I noticed this while transferring it to codepen.

```css
  .diglett {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  }

  .body {
  height: 230px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #b1917e;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #040202;
  border-right: 2px solid #040202;
  border-left: 2px solid #040202;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  }

  .head-shine {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 140px;
  color: #c9b3a4;
  background-color:currentColor;
  filter: blur(8px);
  border-radius: 100px / 50px;
  transform: rotate(160deg);
  z-index: 1;
  }

  .head-shine2 {
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  top: -250px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #b49580;
  filter: blur(10px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(80deg);
  }

  .left-eye{
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 8px;
  border-radius: 40% 40%;
  color: black;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  box-shadow: 
      inset -1px -6px 7px -2px #595a5a;
  border: solid 2px black;
  left: 45.4%;
  top: 8%;
  z-index: 2;
  }

  .right-eye{
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 8px;
  border-radius: 40% 40%;
  color: black;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  box-shadow: 
      inset -1px -6px 7px -2px #595a5a;
  border: solid 2px black;
  left: 50%;
  top: 8.2%;
  z-index: 2 ;
  }

  .eye-shines{
  position: absolute;
  height: 7px;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 45.7%;
  top: 8.2%;
  box-shadow: 
      9.7vmin 0 0 0 white;
  z-index: 8;
  filter: blur(0.8px);
  transform: rotate(2deg);
  }

  .mouth {
  position: absolute;
  height: 41px;
  width: 77px;
  background-color: #b982a2;
  border-radius: 46% 46% 46% 46%;
  border: 3px solid #040202;
  left: 44.6%;
  top: 14.5%;
  z-index: 2;
  }

  .mouth-shine {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #e5b6d3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 45%;
  top: 15.3%;
  z-index: 3;
  filter: blur(2px);
  }

  .mouth-shine2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 18px;
  background-color: #f4e4f0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
  left: 45.8%;
  top: 16.2%;
  z-index: 4;
  filter: blur(1.5px);
  }

  .soil{
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #828388;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  transform: translate(80%, -55%);
  filter: 
      drop-shadow(0 2px black)
      drop-shadow(0 -2px black)
      drop-shadow(2px 0 black)
      drop-shadow(-2px 0 black);
  color: #828388;
  box-shadow: 
      -6vmin 1vmin 0 -2vmin,
      -12vmin 1vmin 0 -1vmin,
      7vmin 1.25vmin 0 -1.75vmin, 
      12vmin 1.25vmin 0 -1.25vmin,
      -18vmin 1.25vmin 0 -1.25vmin,
      18vmin 1.25vmin 0 -1.25vmin;
  z-index: 6; 
  }
```

```html
  <html>
  <head>
<title>Diglett</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="diglett">
      <div class="body">
          <div class="eyes">
              <div class="left-eye"></div>
              <div class="right-eye"></div>
              <div class="eye-shines"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="head">
              <div class="head-shine"></div>
              <div class="head-shine2"></div>
          </div>
              <div class="mouth"></div>
              <div class="mouth-shine"></div>
              <div class="mouth-shine2"></div>
          <div class="soil"></div>
      </div>  
  </div>    
  </body>
  </html>
```

**Full codepen:** https://codepen.io/devjuanv/pen/qBjYgEB

So: 1) could u help me updating the code so it looks as intended in every viewport? and 2) could you provide at least a short explanation on what you did?

It would mean lot for my learning! Thank u!!!

This is how it looks on my desktop: [image: This is how it looks on my desktop, I like it!]

Comment: use `em` instead of `px` and also, `1em = 4px`

Comment: I changed everything to em and, while it looks a little bit more responsive size-wise, the positioning it's even messier :(

Comment: can u post the image of how the diglet looks in your screen?

Comment: Edited! Thank u for the interest!

Comment: rem units are more consistent than em in my opinion. Percentages are also good. There's also the calc() function for CSS. It's also less confusing and tedious (in my opinion, and considered best practice) to start with a design that works on low resolutions first, and then work your way up. The so-called "mobile first" approach.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, Martin. I'll try the 'mobile first' approach for now on! I still look forward to adapting this drawing though.

Comment: Try putting `:root { font-size: .05vw }` at the start of your styles and changing all `px` units to `rem`. You will still need to make adjustments after, but your drawing will be responsive.